# Choose a sass declaration in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, webstorm

Is there a way to configure Webstorm/Intellij Choose Declartion panel so that when you click on a class declaration in a html file it will jump to the relevant Sass file instead of css?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Follow this ticket (star/comment/vote) to get notified on progress :

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6737

Related:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8190